# how to show username at right side of profile photo using css

Tags: css, html

I created a user profile system with a cover photo upload too but i don't like the way users see their username at the bottom of his/her profile photo;
[image: View image]

in the image above, you can see where the username(Aaron *) is been shown and the red arrow indicates where i want it to be.
I tried inserting the username inside the div containing the image but it always goes at the bottom and sometimes i don't even see it anymore.

*This is my css code for the profile photo and cover photo;*

```
.profile_photo {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
    -moz-border-radius: 50%;
    overflow:hidden;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.profile_photo img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.cover_photo {
    height: 110px;
}
```

*and this is the code for the users profile*

```
<div class="cover_photo" style="<?php echo $cover_photo; ?>">
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle pull-right m-opt-prof" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    <span class="icon icon-option"></span>
                </a>
                <br>
                <br>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right m-prof-link-opt" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Dropdown1
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Dropdown2
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Dropdown3
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="edit_profile">
                            Edit profile
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="profile_photo">
                <?php echo $profile_photo; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
<div id="spro_d_d">
      <div id="spro_d">
              <b>
                <?php echo $username; ?>    
              </b> 
              <?php echo $status_online; ?><br>
        <p>
          <font color="#656565">
            <?php echo $full_name; ?>
          </font><br>
          <?php echo nl2br($bio); ?>
        </p>
        <?php echo '<span class="icon icon-website spro_m_d" title="website"></span>&nbsp;'.$set_site; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo '<span class="icon icon-location spro_m_d" title="location"></span>&nbsp;'.$location; ?>
          </div>
    </div>
    <hr class="hr_line">
    <div id="u_pff_st_b">
        <div class="row">
          <div id="u_pff_st" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <a href="#post">
              0<br>
              Posts
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="u_pff_st" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <a href="#followers">
              0<br>
              Followers
            </a>
          </div>
          <div id="u_pff_st" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
            <a href="#following">
              0<br>
              Following
            </a>
          </div>
        </div> <!-- row -->
    </div>
```

the `<?php echo $cover_photo; ?>` holds this;

```
background: url(../users/uploads/profile/default.jpg) no-repeat 50% 50%;
```

and the `<?php echo $profile_photo; ?>` holds this;

```
<img src='../users/uploads/profile/$current_photo' alt='$username' title='$username'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your username inside `profile_photo` .

`I tried inserting the username inside the div containing the image but it always goes at the bottom and sometimes i don't even see it anymore.` . That is because of the `overflow:hidden` style on `profile_photo`. So,
remove the `overflow:hidden` from the styles and add styles to the `img` not the `profile_photo` div. ( border-radius, width, height etc. )

Then , to center the text inside the `profile_photo` div, you can use `display:flex;align-items:center`

see below

```css
.profile_photo {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.profile_photo img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
}


/*.cover_photo {
   height: 110px;
}*/

.profile_photo {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center
}
```

```html
<div class="cover_photo" style="background:red">


  <div class="dropdown">
    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle pull-right m-opt-prof" type="button" id="menu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
      <span class="icon icon-option"></span>
    </a>
    <br>
    <br>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right m-prof-link-opt" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
      <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Dropdown1
                        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Dropdown2
                        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">
                            Dropdown3
                        </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
        <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="edit_profile">
                            Edit profile
                        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="profile_photo">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150">
    <b>
               UserName
              </b>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="spro_d_d">
  <div id="spro_d">

    Online
    <p>
      <font color="#656565">
            Full Name
          </font>
      <br> Bio bio bio
    </p>
    <?php echo '<span class="icon icon-website spro_m_d" title="website"></span>&nbsp;'.$set_site; ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <?php echo '<span class="icon icon-location spro_m_d" title="location"></span>&nbsp;'.$location; ?>
  </div>
</div>
<hr class="hr_line">
<div id="u_pff_st_b">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="u_pff_st" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
      <a href="#post">
              0<br>
              Posts
            </a>
    </div>
    <div id="u_pff_st" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
      <a href="#followers">
              0<br>
              Followers
            </a>
    </div>
    <div id="u_pff_st" class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4">
      <a href="#following">
              0<br>
              Following
            </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- row -->
</div>
```

Comment: @Dev.aaron glad i could help. Cheers ! :D